# When deploying an ml model using vscode I get an error docker image build failed

Tags: python, azure, docker, visual-studio-code, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm following this tutorial [VSCODE tensorflow model deployment on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-train-deploy-image-classification-model-vscode).
Here instead of tensorflow model I'm trying to deploy a simple decision tree model.I create a train.py file like this

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import pickle
import os
import joblib

data=pd.read_csv('CreditCardWeka.csv')
model=DecisionTreeClassifier()
Y=data['Class']
del data['Class']
X=data
model.fit(X,Y)
os.makedirs('./outputs/model', exist_ok = True)
joblib.dump(model, './outputs/model/dec_model.sav')
```

After this I create a compute,create a run configuration and select this file.After this I create an experiment and run it and download the output.I'm able to download the output and till here it works.
After this I'm able to successfully register my model and when I try to deploy it as an "Azure Container Service" it asks for score.py while which is this

```
import os
import joblib
import json
import time
import sklearn
# Called when the deployed service starts
from azureml.core.model import Model

def init():
    global model

    # Get the path where the deployed model can be found.
    # load models
    model_root = Model.get_model_path('decision-tree-model')
    model = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_root, 'dec-model.sav'))

# Handle requests to the service
def run(data):
    try:
        # Pick out the text property of the JSON request.
        # This expects a request in the form of {"text": "some text to score for sentiment"}
        data = json.loads(data)
        prediction = model.predict(data['X'])
        #Return prediction
        return prediction
    except Exception as e:
        error = str(e)
        return error
```

It also asks for a yml file which is this

```
name: decision-tree
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python
  - sklearn
  - joblib
  - pip
  - pip:
    - azureml-defaults
```

After this when it starts creating a docker image it failes and the error is "Docker image build failed".
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the yml file, try changing the sklearn to scikit-learn.

If it still fails, try the detailed troubleshooting instructions to get more logs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment